# html table tbody scroll without td contents break into multiple lines

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table, need to have a fixed header and tbody scroll.I have found lot of solutions in stackoverflow which helps a lot, but i am facing a problem like ,the contents inside th and td is breaking into multiple lines.

[image]

which is not happening when no css is added for the scroll bar

[image]

I want to apply scrollbar as well as contents should not be break into multiple lines.guys pls help me out how to achieve this, without applying lot of inline styles to the tds

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title> Materialize.css Admin Data Table </title>
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    #products-table tbody {
      display: block;
      height: 400px;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
    #products-table thead,
    #products-table tbody tr {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      table-layout: fixed;
    }
    
    #products-table {
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table id="products-table" class="bordered products-table centered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>S.No</th>
          <th>Product Name</th>
          <th>Product Category</th>
          <th>Tax Name</th>
          <th>Tax(%)</th>
          <th>Tax Value</th>
          <th>Product Price</th>
          <th>Price With Tax</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="products-table-tbody">
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Aloo Chaat Masala</td>
          <td>Grill</td>
          <td>GST</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>4.45</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>89.00</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>93.45</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
            <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Du Barry</td>
          <td>Grill</td>
          <td>GST</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>4.45</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>89.00</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>93.45</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
            <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Vegetable Stacks</td>
          <td>Grill</td>
          <td>GST</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>4.45</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>89.00</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>93.45</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
            <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Grilled Mediterranean</td>
          <td>Grill</td>
          <td>GST</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>4.95</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>99.00</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>103.95</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
            <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>Mushroom Medley</td>
          <td>Grill</td>
          <td>GST</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>4.45</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>89.00</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>93.45</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
            <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>BBQ Cottage Cheese</td>
          <td>Grill</td>
          <td>GST</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>4.95</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>99.00</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>103.95</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
            <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>Chatpata Paneer Bhurji</td>
          <td>Grill</td>
          <td>GST</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>4.95</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>99.00</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>103.95</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
            <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>Grilled Chicken</td>
          <td>Grill</td>
          <td>GST</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>5.45</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>109.00</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>114.45</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
            <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>Portuguese BBQ Chorizo</td>
          <td>Grill</td>
          <td>GST</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6.45</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>129.00</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>135.45</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
            <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>Pulled Chicken Tandoori</td>
          <td>Grill</td>
          <td>GST</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>5.45</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>109.00</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>114.45</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
            <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>Pollo A LA Caccitore</td>
          <td>Grill</td>
          <td>GST</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>5.95</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>119.00</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>124.95</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
            <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Aloo Chaat Masala</td>
          <td>Grill</td>
          <td>GST</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>4.45</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>89.00</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>93.45</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
            <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>Du Barry</td>
          <td>Grill</td>
          <td>GST</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>4.45</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>89.00</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>93.45</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
            <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>Vegetable Stacks</td>
          <td>Grill</td>
          <td>GST</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>4.45</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>89.00</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>93.45</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
            <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>Grilled Mediterranean</td>
          <td>Grill</td>
          <td>GST</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>4.95</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>99.00</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>103.95</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
            <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>Mushroom Medley</td>
          <td>Grill</td>
          <td>GST</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>4.45</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>89.00</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>93.45</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
            <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>BBQ Cottage Cheese</td>
          <td>Grill</td>
          <td>GST</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>4.95</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>99.00</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>103.95</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
            <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>Chatpata Paneer Bhurji</td>
          <td>Grill</td>
          <td>GST</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>4.95</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>99.00</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>103.95</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
            <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>Grilled Chicken</td>
          <td>Grill</td>
          <td>GST</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>5.45</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>109.00</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>114.45</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
            <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>Portuguese BBQ Chorizo</td>
          <td>Grill</td>
          <td>GST</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6.45</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>129.00</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>135.45</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
            <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>Pulled Chicken Tandoori</td>
          <td>Grill</td>
          <td>GST</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>5.45</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>109.00</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>114.45</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
            <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>Pollo A LA Caccitore</td>
          <td>Grill</td>
          <td>GST</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>5.95</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>119.00</td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>124.95</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
            <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Slim Scroll -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-slimScroll/1.3.8/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is the width 100% an attribute for both theversions of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achive the goal you can hide the overflow and word wrapping like as follows.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title> Materialize.css Admin Data Table </title>
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        #products-table tbody{
            display:block;
            height:400px;
            overflow:auto;
        }
         #products-table thead tr th,
        #products-table tbody tr td{
               overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }
        #products-table thead,
        #products-table tbody tr{
            display:table;
            width:100%;
            table-layout:fixed;
        }
        #products-table{
            border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
            width:100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <table id="products-table" class="bordered products-table centered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>S.No</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Product Category</th>
                <th>Tax Name</th>
                <th>Tax(%)</th>
                <th>Tax Value</th>
                <th>Product Price</th>
                <th>Price With Tax</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="products-table-tbody">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Aloo Chaat Masala</td>
                <td>Grill</td>
                <td>GST</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>4.45</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>89.00</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>93.45</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
                    <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Du Barry</td>
                <td>Grill</td>
                <td>GST</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>4.45</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>89.00</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>93.45</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
                    <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Vegetable Stacks</td>
                <td>Grill</td>
                <td>GST</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>4.45</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>89.00</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>93.45</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
                    <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Grilled Mediterranean</td>
                <td>Grill</td>
                <td>GST</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>4.95</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>99.00</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>103.95</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
                    <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>Mushroom Medley</td>
                <td>Grill</td>
                <td>GST</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>4.45</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>89.00</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>93.45</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
                    <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>BBQ Cottage Cheese</td>
                <td>Grill</td>
                <td>GST</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>4.95</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>99.00</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>103.95</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
                    <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>Chatpata Paneer Bhurji</td>
                <td>Grill</td>
                <td>GST</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>4.95</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>99.00</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>103.95</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
                    <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>Grilled Chicken</td>
                <td>Grill</td>
                <td>GST</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>5.45</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>109.00</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>114.45</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
                    <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>Portuguese BBQ Chorizo</td>
                <td>Grill</td>
                <td>GST</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6.45</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>129.00</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>135.45</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
                    <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>Pulled Chicken Tandoori</td>
                <td>Grill</td>
                <td>GST</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>5.45</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>109.00</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>114.45</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
                    <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>Pollo A LA Caccitore</td>
                <td>Grill</td>
                <td>GST</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>5.95</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>119.00</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>124.95</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
                    <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Aloo Chaat Masala</td>
                <td>Grill</td>
                <td>GST</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>4.45</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>89.00</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>93.45</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
                    <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>Du Barry</td>
                <td>Grill</td>
                <td>GST</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>4.45</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>89.00</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>93.45</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
                    <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>Vegetable Stacks</td>
                <td>Grill</td>
                <td>GST</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>4.45</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>89.00</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>93.45</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
                    <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>Grilled Mediterranean</td>
                <td>Grill</td>
                <td>GST</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>4.95</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>99.00</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>103.95</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
                    <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>Mushroom Medley</td>
                <td>Grill</td>
                <td>GST</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>4.45</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>89.00</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>93.45</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
                    <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>BBQ Cottage Cheese</td>
                <td>Grill</td>
                <td>GST</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>4.95</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>99.00</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>103.95</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
                    <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>16</td>
                <td>Chatpata Paneer Bhurji</td>
                <td>Grill</td>
                <td>GST</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>4.95</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>99.00</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>103.95</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
                    <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>17</td>
                <td>Grilled Chicken</td>
                <td>Grill</td>
                <td>GST</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>5.45</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>109.00</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>114.45</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
                    <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>18</td>
                <td>Portuguese BBQ Chorizo</td>
                <td>Grill</td>
                <td>GST</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6.45</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>129.00</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>135.45</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
                    <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>Pulled Chicken Tandoori</td>
                <td>Grill</td>
                <td>GST</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>5.45</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>109.00</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>114.45</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
                    <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>Pollo A LA Caccitore</td>
                <td>Grill</td>
                <td>GST</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>5.95</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>119.00</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>124.95</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-small">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                </button>
                    <button class="btn-small red">
                                    <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Slim Scroll -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-slimScroll/1.3.8/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you can add a CSS property

```
td {
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

Hope it will help.